# Loop to use concat function when only one file available

Tags: python, pandas

I have a lot of folders with same file name as `'profile_inst.out'` and when I concat using below command then it works fine. However, when I only have one file then it give value error as

> "ValueError: No objects to concatenate".

As I understand because it only has one file and nothing to pd.concat to.

`dpi = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f,delim_whitespace=True,low_memory=False) for f in glob.glob('profile_inst.out')],ignore_index = True)`

Now with my data it is sometime possible that I only have one large file then how can I keep the same code for reading one or multiple files using pd.concat function in pandas.

Help will be much appreciated..thanks

Comment: what is the result of `glob.glob('profile_inst.out')` ? do you get a list of files?

Comment: Put an if else that checks for len of files in the folder and acts accordingly? More lines of code doesn't necessarily mean bad coding.